# How to achieve radio button animation of border sliding over from one radio to another radio button on selection?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, tailwind-css, css-animations, headless-ui

I have a react application where there is a requirement to implement a radio button like this. I have implemented my radio buttons successfully but I can't implement the toggling animation where the borders slide over. I'm using tailwind and headless UI for creating the components. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the animation I want to achieve -> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCLYO.gif)

My radio component is as follows:

```
const RadioButton = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IRadioButtonProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { label, selected, ...rest } = props;
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return (
      <span
        className={cn(
          "py-3 px-4 bg-white rounded-md flex gap-x-3 w-auto border-2 border-primary-50 relative",
          {
            "bg-primary-50 border-primary": selected,
          },
        )}
      >
        <span
          className={cn(
            "w-6 h-6 rounded-full border border-graphite-300 focus-visible:outline-yellow-400 focus:outline-focus",
          )}
        >
          <Transition
            show={selected}
            enter="transition-opacity duration-500"
            enterFrom="opacity-0"
            enterTo="opacity-100"
            leave="transition-opacity duration-400"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Icon
              tabIndex={0}
              src={radioCheck}
              alt={t("common.iconAltText.checked")}
              size={24}
              className="focus-visible:outline-yellow-400 focus:outline-focus rounded-full"
            />
          </Transition>
        </span>
        <input
          {...rest}
          type="radio"
          tabIndex={-1}
          className={cn(
            rest.className,
            "absolute w-full h-full opacity-0 top-0 left-0 cursor-pointer",
          )}
          ref={ref}
        />
        <label htmlFor={rest.id}>{label}</label>
      </span>
    );
  },
);
```

I've used `Transition` from Headless UI to fade in fade out the checkmark when toggling selection